# Can not generate correct wsdl with cxf-java2ws-plugin

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf

I'm trying to generate a wsdl file from MyWebService interface;

```
public interface MyWebService{
    public ResponseMessage processService(MyWSData myWSData);
}
```

and here's the java classes

```
public class MyWSData extends Message {
    private String myString;
    private MyOtherClass[] myOtherClassArray;  
    private Long myLong;
}

public class MyOtherClass{
    private Long id;
    private String name;
}
```

and here is my pom.xml file

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                <artifactId>cxf-java2ws-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-simple</artifactId>
                        <version>2.4.3</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>process-classes</id>
                        <phase>process-classes</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <className>com.ferdisonmezay.webservice.MyWebService</className>
                            <genWsdl>true</genWsdl>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <genClient>false</genClient>
                            <serviceName>MyWebService</serviceName>
                            <targetNameSpace>some-namespace-here</targetNameSpace>
                            <argline> -createxsdimports </argline>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>java2ws</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

in my generated wsdl file:
MyOtherClass array field looks empty

```
<xs:complexType name="myOtherClassArray">
    <xs:sequence/>
  </xs:complexType>
```

what should be the reason, or is there any other way to generate a correct wsdl file including MyOtherClass[]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. That's a very old version of CXF.
2. Without accessors, JAX-B can't do anything with MyOtherClass. Try adding public getters and setters to the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. CXF 2.5.2 java2ws doesn't like generating from interfaces, because it needs an implementation to instantiate in the generated server.  So generate from a class that implements your interface.
2. The class that implements MyWebService needs to be annotated with @javax.jws.WebService, and the method processService() in that class needs to be annotated with @javax.jws.WebMethod - java2ws will only generate WSDL for the methods you want it to.  You can of course use import javax.jws.WebService; and just annotate with @WebService, etc.